# Recursive query on same table MySQL and concat column

Tags: mysql

Below is my table:

I have the below table structure :

```
id        |  parentid     | Name
1         |  NULL         | W
2         |  1            | O
3         |  1            | R
4         |  2            | L
5         |  4            | D
```

I hope to get the following result, the result will recursively find the `parentid` until it found `parentid` of `NULL`. It will append all the `Name` and create a new column called `Code`

```
id        |  parentid     | Name | Code
1         |  NULL         | W    | W
2         |  1            | O    | W,O
3         |  1            | R    | W,R
4         |  2            | L    | W,O,L
5         |  4            | D    | W,O,L,D
```

This is what I have tried:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte as 
( 
    SELECT  id, 
            id nextid, 
            parentid
    FROM    table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cte.id, 
            t1.id, 
            t1.parentid
    FROM    table
    JOIN    cte 
    ON      cte.parentid = p.id
)
SELECT Id, nextid RootId
FROM cte
WHERE parentid IS NULL
```

Comment: Please do not use reserved words for table names (like `table`), and make sure that your post valid SQL statements, or post the complete error message (`Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'`,  but also later a reference to `p.id` ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

The `CAST()` here is to make the Code column wider.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte as 
( 
    SELECT  id, 
            parentid, 
            name,
            CAST(name AS CHAR(50)) AS Code
    FROM    mytable where parentid is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t1.id, 
            t1.parentid,
            t1.name,
            CONCAT(c.Code, ',', t1.name)
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN    mytable t1
    ON      c.id = t1.parentid
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tcGoSSPy97n8z63CzmZt85/1)